# WF 4.5 Compile CSharpValue<T> error. What is the correct method?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I've been uniting testing two simple examples of compiling `CSharpValue` activities. One works and the other doesn't I can't figure out why. If someone could point out the issue and optionally a change to correct it if possible.

Details:

The first `unit test` works `SequenceActivityCompile()` the second `CodeActivityCompile` fails with a `NotSupportedException` (Expression Activity type `CSharpValue` requires compilation in order to run.  Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled.)

I heard somewhere this can be related to `ForImplementation` but `CodeActivityCompile` has the same error whether its value is true or false.

This example is a basic adaption of the Microsoft example at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591618(v=vs.110).aspx

This example blog post discussing compiling C# expressions in WF 4+ at length. If anyone reaching this question needs a basic introduction to the topic:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2012/05/25/wf4-5-using-csharpvalue-lt-t-gt-and-csharpreference-lt-t-gt-in-net-4-5-compiling-expressions-and-changes-in-visual-studio-generated-xaml.aspx

Related Code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SequenceActivityCompile()
    {



        Activity sequence = new Sequence
        {
            Activities = { new CSharpValue<string>("\"Hello World \"") }
        };


        CompileExpressions(sequence);
        var result = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(sequence);


    }



    [TestMethod]
    public void CodeActivityCompile()
    {

        var code = new CSharpValue<String>("\"Hello World\"");
        CompileExpressions(code);
        var result = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(code);


    }


    void CompileExpressions(Activity activity)
    {
        // activityName is the Namespace.Type of the activity that contains the
        // C# expressions.
        string activityName = activity.GetType().ToString();

        // Split activityName into Namespace and Type.Append _CompiledExpressionRoot to the type name
        // to represent the new type that represents the compiled expressions.
        // Take everything after the last . for the type name.
        //string activityType = activityName.Split('.').Last() + "_CompiledExpressionRoot";
        string activityType = "TestType";
        // Take everything before the last . for the namespace.
        //string activityNamespace = string.Join(".", activityName.Split('.').Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse());
        string activityNamespace = "TestSpace";

        // Create a TextExpressionCompilerSettings.
        TextExpressionCompilerSettings settings = new TextExpressionCompilerSettings
        {
            Activity = activity,
            Language = "C#",
            ActivityName = activityType,
            ActivityNamespace = activityNamespace,
            RootNamespace = null,
            GenerateAsPartialClass = false,
            AlwaysGenerateSource = true,
            ForImplementation = false
        };

        // Compile the C# expression.
        TextExpressionCompilerResults results =
            new TextExpressionCompiler(settings).Compile();

        // Any compilation errors are contained in the CompilerMessages.
        if (results.HasErrors)
        {
            throw new Exception("Compilation failed.");
        }

        // Create an instance of the new compiled expression type.
        ICompiledExpressionRoot compiledExpressionRoot =
            Activator.CreateInstance(results.ResultType,
                new object[] { activity }) as ICompiledExpressionRoot;

        // Attach it to the activity.
        System.Activities.Expressions.CompiledExpressionInvoker.SetCompiledExpressionRoot(
            activity, compiledExpressionRoot);
    }
```